# How to track changes in Eventlistener and write them into DB?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to monitor what happens in my app. For this I created this class:

```
class ChangeLogListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'postPersist',
            'postUpdate',
            'onDelete',
        );
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        # Avoid to log the logging process
        if (!$args->getEntity() instanceof ChangeLog)

            $this->createLog($args, 'creation');
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

        $this->createLog($args, 'update');
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        # Handle the log creation
        $this->createLog($args, 'remove');
    }

    public function createLog(LifecycleEventArgs $args, $action)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        $changes[] = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

        $cl = new ChangeLog();
        $cl->setDate(new \DateTime());
        $cl->setUser($user);
        $cl->setEntityName(get_class($entity));
        $cl->setEntityId($entity->getId());
        $cl->setAction($action);
        $cl->setChangeset($changes);//<---change this 
        $cl->setDescription('');

        $em->persist($cl);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

But I have some problems with changes, I don't know how I can correctly write them into the DB and make them readable. Maybe there are some methods to do this correctly?
When I try to flush changes, I always get error:

> String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column
>   'change_set' at row 1"

My ChangeLog.orm.yml:

```
#...
fields:
   changeSet:
         type: array
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `var_dump($changes);die();` after your `getEntityChangeSet()` line and figure out what you actually want from that data set. It is currently too long for the field you are trying to save it in. It will need to be reduced.